# Help me identify the hash type

Tags: hash

Please help me identify this Hash Code.
'$1$DN$VSrllqW7nePlu.jmavF07.'
I have never seen such hash code.

Comment: It's a md5-crypt password hash: `$ openssl passwd -1 -salt DN 1q2w3e4r` --> `$1$DN$VSrllqW7nePlu.jmavF07.`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a **SHA1 shrink** .

SHA1 is cryptographically secure but weighs in uses 40 characters, which is pretty long if you're going to be passing the data around in a URL/cookie or something similar.

There are special functions that reduce SHA1 hash down to just **27 characters** by using a base65 encoding that only uses **URL-safe characters**.

This looks **exactly like your case**.

Looks like the correct solution is
md5-crypt password hash: `$ openssl passwd -1 -salt DN 1q2w3e4r' --> '$1$DN$VSrllqW7nePlu.jmavF07.`

Thanks Arminius.

Comment: On the contrary, this looks infinitely more likely to be a [Linux password hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passwd#Shadow_file).

Comment: The beginning looks like that, but I don't think those would use SHA-1 shrinks. the linux MD5 hash should be $1+32 characters (34 chars in total).

Comment: @Overmind I commented the "solution" below the question. You might want to include that in your answer.